# Why MQL4 Backtest RSI values do not match with RSI on chart?

Tags: mql4, trading, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4

I have a simple backtest of below EA:

```
    void OnTick()
    {
       double rsi = iRSI( Symbol(), PERIOD_M5, 14, PRICE_CLOSE, 0 );
       
       int day  = TimeDay(    TimeCurrent() );
       int hour = TimeHour(   TimeCurrent() );
       int min  = TimeMinute( TimeCurrent() );
       if (  day  ==  7
          && hour >=  9
          && hour <  11
             ) {      
          Print( Symbol(), " / ", PERIOD_M5, " rsi: ", (string) rsi );
       }
    }
```

However, the backtest log seems does not match with show in the chart as this image:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLpvI.png

Could you please give some explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Could you please give some explanation?"*

Sure, your code calculates & updates a printed `RSI(14)`-value (per-tick)

Kindly notice, that the previous bar 08:55 has finished with `RSI(14)`-value well above the `HLINE ~ 30%` (if in doubts, one can initially `Print( iRSI( Symbol(), PERIOD_M5, 14, PRICE_CLOSE, 1 ) );` where you will see the "previous"-bar value numerically.

From about that value ( above ~ 30% ) the newly opened bar `[0]` will start to "develop" the actual `RSI(14)`-value, inside the new bar. So, initially, the values will "move" and the graph plots / redraws the line ( we can visualise each such change as a dot, marker or a Hi/Lo-range ), which is **THE REASON**, why we finally see a blue line fallen to the position, where the `Close[0]` has "finished" upon exiting of the bar under review (the 09:00 one, at about the 09:04:59:9999 time).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Modify and use custom RSI from MetaQuotes instead of "Oscillators/Relative Strength Index" to draw the RSI with DRAW_ARROW mode as below help me to understand your reply.
http://i.imgur.com/lvLEdWQ.png